# How to use tensor flow to build a CNN model where each "branch" is separate until being joined at the last step?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, computer-vision

This is quite hard to express in words clearly, so please let me know if you have any questions.

I am training a image recognition model using CNN. But I have images of different angles, so I want to do several layers with each angle of n pictures. In this process, I decrease the output of each angle to 1, and in the end, I combine this output of all angles and do a 2 layers neural network.

I tried to train one angle as test and got working result, then I put each layer of each angle into a list as I go along the same step,(a list of convolutional layer1 for all angles, a list of pooling layer1, a list of convolutional layer2, a list of pooling layer2 ... ) except I add the last step of combining them and do the final logistic layer and get a 0/1 output.

I got tons of errors like Key conv2d_7/bias not found in checkpoint.

So instead of debugging, I'm wondering if this is a valid way to do it in the first place? Is it possible that when I put all the layers in different lists, the model can't find some of the values in the flow?

If not, what should I do to achieve this goal of training each angle separately and then combine the result and do final training towards 0/1?

Thanks a lot.

Here is the code:

```
def model_train(features, labels, mode):
    input_list = []
    conv1_list = []
    pool1_list = []
    conv2_list = []
    pool2_list = []
    conv3_list = []
    pool3_list = []
    pool3_flat_list = []
    dense1_list = []
    dense2_list = []
    logit1_list = []
    feature = tf.transpose(features["x"],[1,0,2,3])
    for i in range(0,11,1):
        input_list.append(tf.reshape(feature[i], [-1, 73, 135, 1]))

        conv1_list.append(tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=input_list[i],
            filters=10,
            kernel_size=[5, 5],
            padding="same",
            activation=tf.nn.relu))
        pool1_list.append(tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1_list[i], pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2))
        conv2_list.append(tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=pool1_list[i],
            filters=20,
            kernel_size=[3, 3],
            padding="same",
            activation=tf.nn.relu))
        pool2_list.append(tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2_list[i], pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2))
        conv3_list.append(tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=pool2_list[i],
            filters=30,
            kernel_size=[5, 5],
            padding="same",
            activation=tf.nn.relu))
        pool3_list.append(tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3_list[i], pool_size=[3, 3], strides=3))
        pool3_flat_list.append(tf.reshape(pool3_list[i], [-1, 6*11*30]))
        dense1_list.append(tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool3_flat_list[i], units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        dense2_list.append(tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1_list[i], units=16, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        logit1_list.append(tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense2_list[i],units=1))


    # nn of 11 separate results
    input2 = tf.reshape(logit1_list,[11,-1])
    input2 = tf.transpose(input2)
    dense3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = input2, units = 64)
    logit2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = dense3, units = 2)



    predictions = {
        # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logit2, axis=1),
        # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
        # `logging_hook`.
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logit2, name="softmax_tensor")
    }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=2)
    onehot_labels = tf.squeeze(onehot_labels, axis=1)
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logit2)

    # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

    # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
    eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(argv=None):
    dropbox_dir = '/Users/someone/Dropbox'
    csv_dir = dropbox_dir + '/ML/CSInde/stage1_labels.csv'
    zone13_dir = dropbox_dir + '/ML/zone13/'

    image_list, label_list = read_labeled_image_list(csv_dir)
    labels = np.asarray(label_list, dtype=np.int32)
    labels = np.reshape(labels, [1147, 1])

    images = read_images_from_disk(image_list)

    model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_train, model_dir="/tmp/test_model")
    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}

    logging = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
        tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": images},
        y=labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=False)
    model.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        steps=20000,
        hooks=[logging]
    )
    print('finishTrain++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    # a = tf.Print(tf.shape(images), [tf.shape(images)])
    # b = tf.add(a, a).eval()
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": images},
        y=labels,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)
    eval_results = model.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_results)
```

I didn't post the part where I read in data since I don't think that is causing the problems. So I just post the model part and the main method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you did should work. The code is not attached so I cannot see what is the exact problem in saving/loading of the model.

My guess though, is that you don't follow the training code convention in the evaluation code. The reason I think so is because the name`conv2d_7/bias` is not angle dependent.

So - if you declared your layers with angle specific names, or prefix, make sure you also use that same name in your evaluation code. i.e, for angle 30, you have to define `conv2d_7-angle_30/bias` (or however you named it), instead of `conv2d_7/bias`.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, could you please have a look at the code? We didn't actually dig into the model and name the variables. I put all of them in different lists, those are basically all the variable names I have.

Comment: where is the error? `eval_results = model.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)`?